# Issues with uploading a file to replace table in database

Tags: node.js, web-applications, file-upload, express, mongoose

I am trying to upload a file containing an array of multiple objects and use it to replace the table in my mongoose database.  This is what the file looks like:

```
var newRooms = [
    {name: "yogaStudio",
    title: "Yoga Studio",
    description: "This is where StarFleet officers go to get bendy",
    roomExits: ['kitchen', 'foyer'],}
    ,

    {name: "kitchen",
    title: "Kitchen",
    description: "You must be starving, please come in and make yourself a sandwich",
    roomExits: ['yogaStudio', 'drawingroom'],}
    , 

    {name: "foyer",
    title: "Foyer",
    description: "This is the entrance hallway",
    roomExits: ['yogaStudio', 'kitchen'],},

    {name: "drawingroom",
    title: "Drawing Room",
    description: "Please grab a drink and take a seat, it's stressful navigating around this place",
    roomExits: ['kitchen', 'foyer'],}
    ,
];
```

These are the functions I am using to upload and replace:

```
var restore = function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(req.files.roomFile.path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
           res.send("File upload error.");
        } else {
           overwriteDB(JSON.parse(data), res);
        }
    });
}

var overwriteDB = function(newDB, res) {
    if (!Array.isArray(newDB)) {
        res.send("Error: Data structure isn't an array.");
        return;
    }    
   // Should validate newDB further before deleting old documents.
   Room.remove({}, function(err) { 
        if (err) {
           res.send("Error: Couldn't delete all existing documents" +
            "on restore.");
           return;
        } else {
           console.log("All documents removed before restore.");
        }

        newDB.forEach(function(theRoomtoImport) {
        var theRoom = new Room(theRoomtoImport);
            theRoom.save(function(err, theRoom) {
                if (err) {
                   console.log("Failure restoring " + theRoom.name);
                } else {
                   console.log("Success restoring " + theRoom.name);
                }
            });
        });
        res.send("Restore in progress!");
    });
}
```

But I'm getting this ERROR

```
sarah@superawesome:~/comp2406/adventure-ajax-demo$ node app.js
Express server listening on port 3000

undefined:1
var newRooms = [
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /home/sarah/comp2406/adventure-ajax-demo/routes/index.js:75:23
    at fs.js:252:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first file is javascript, not JSON.

If it's intended to be JSON, just do this:

```
[
    {name: "yogaStudio",
    title: "Yoga Studio",
    description: "This is where StarFleet officers go to get bendy",
    roomExits: ['kitchen', 'foyer'],}
    ,
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's tricky keeping everything straight

Do I end the array like this ]; or just ]?

Comment: just ] you can use a web based json validator to double check your work

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of

```
var newRooms =
```

JSON.parse cannot parse this as valid json string.